# User with no privileges can alter table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to do a test to prove the privileges of the users. I have one user with just one privilege (execute programs) but when I try this, this user can alter table:

```
SHOW USER;
CONNECT USER1/USER1;
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (colum int); //Insufficient privileges
SHOW USER;
ALTER TABLE TABLE_TESTING ADD TESTING varchar(255);
```

So, I'm getting insufficient privileges on create table but when I do ALTER TABLE the user can do it and I don't know why because I select only the privilege of execute programs

Comment: either there is a synonym for table TABLE_TESTING or USER1 is the owner of that table, and as owner he is allowed to alter...

Comment: Typically you would address this in a production database by not giving out the password or by revoking `create session` privilege from `USER1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I see it: follow the example.

As a privileged user (`SYS` in my XE database), I'll create user and grant only two privileges: `create session` (so that user could connect to the database) and `create table` (so that it can create tables):

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL>
SQL> create user timer identified by timer
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session, create table to timer;

Grant succeeded.
```

Connecting as newly created user and creating a simple table:

```
SQL> connect timer/timer
Connected.
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.
```

Back to `SYS`: this time, revoking `create table` privilege:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> revoke create table from timer;

Revoke succeeded.
```

Back to `timer`: creating table won't succeed (as I don't have that privilege any more):

```
SQL> connect timer/timer
Connected.
SQL> create table test_table (colum int);
create table test_table (colum int)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

But, I can still `alter` previously created tables. Why? Because I **own** them and I can do whatever I want with them:

```
SQL> alter table test add testing varchar2(20);

Table altered.
```

---

I suggest you talk to your DBA to see what's really going on.

Comment: So, there is no way to prevent user modify his own table?

Answer (score 1):

That might be because the user has the rights to execute which means he's able to alter tables by executing code, but he is not allowed to create new tables explicitly. See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/authoriz.htm#DBSEG5000

Comment: so, how can I grant execute privileges and not allow user to alter table?

Comment: For example by allowing him to execute only pre-defined procedures, that do not change tables. As Turo mentioned in his comment, it is likely, that the table you are altering is owned by the user and that's why he can change it.

Comment: Don't create the table in the USER1 schema and don't explicitly grant USER1 privilege to alter tables in another schema.